# `Error: Failed to determine the layout of your Qt installation` when installing pyqt for python3 on Mavericks

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, homebrew

Running `brew install pyqt --with-python3`, I get `Error: Failed to determine the layout of your Qt installation`. Adding `--verbose` to the brew script, the problem is that ld can't find `-lgcc_s.10.5`.

(This is on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to help other people who encounter this: The solution was to first upgrade XCode to XCode 7.2 and open it once to accept the license and have it install additional components. Then, a `brew update` and a `brew install pyqt --with-python3` finally worked.